# when adding JpaRepository spring gives error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

```
I'm a beginner.
spring project works perfectly, but after adding a JpaRepository interface it no longer initializes the application

My IDE does not show any syntax errors, whenever I compile before adding the JpaRepository the application works
```

MY ONLY CLASS

```
package by.lucas.agenda.contatos.modelo;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Contato {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String telefone;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    private String urlAvatar;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUrlAvatar() {
        return urlAvatar;
    }

    public void setUrlAvatar(String urlAvatar) {
        this.urlAvatar = urlAvatar;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Contato other = (Contato) obj;
        return id == other.id;
    }
    
}


MY INTERFACE
```

package by.lucas.agenda.contatos.modelo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "contatos", path = "contatos")
public interface ContatoRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Contato, Long> {

}

```
POM.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>by.lucas</groupId>
    <artifactId>agenda</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>agenda</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that reload your project to pull new dependencies and once you are done with that alter your imports in your Entity class from javax to jakarta.

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
```

Comment: I made the changes and it worked perfectly. The tutorial I was following used javax, but it looks like spring currently works with jakarta. I am extremely grateful.

Comment: An accepted answer would be greatly appreciated

Comment: As for jakarta, yes, the new version of spring retired javax packages and moved to jakarta. So whenever you see javax dependency, that should be replaced with jakarta

Answer (score 0):

use Intellij IDEA Community edition : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows
it shows all the syntax errors and probable solutions
and it can auto import the package

Comment: This is more of a comment than an Answer.

Comment: I don't have the privilege to comment at the moment because of low reputation

Answer (score 0):

package by.lucas.agenda.contatos.modelo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ContatoRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Contato, Long> {

}